# Error while using pyspark.sql.function on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to import a CSV file using inferred schema. It takes the `orderdate` column as a string. So, I tried to set it to date format by using the `spark.sql.function`. But when I try to show the first 4 rows then an error occurs.

Here is the code!! It working fine if I don't apply the code for correcting the date datatype.
Or if I simply print the schema (using `printSchema()` function) instead of `show()`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

sample_df_inferred = spark.read.csv(
    '../data/sample_data.csv'
    , header=True
    , inferSchema = True
)

# code to correct the date datatype
 
sample_df_inferred = (
    sample_df_inferred
    .withColumn('OrderDate'
                , f.to_date('OrderDate', 'MM/dd/yy')
               )
)

sample_df_inferred.show(4)
```

Error is given below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e3bd2200e9b7> in <module>
     14 )
     15 
---> 16 sample_df_inferred.show(4)

D:\program_files\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    438         """
    439         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 440             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    441         else:
    442             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

D:\program_files\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

D:\program_files\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    126     def deco(*a, **kw):
    127         try:
--> 128             return f(*a, **kw)
    129         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    130             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

D:\program_files\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, LAPTOP-ARQ1E3J3, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '1/6/16' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set it to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkParsedDiff$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkParsedDiff$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:141)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.$anonfun$parse$1(TimestampFormatter.scala:86)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.parse(TimestampFormatter.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1/6/16' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.$anonfun$parse$1(TimestampFormatter.scala:78)
    ... 20 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2120)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3627)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2697)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2697)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:337)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '1/6/16' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkParsedDiff$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkParsedDiff$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:141)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.$anonfun$parse$1(TimestampFormatter.scala:86)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.parse(TimestampFormatter.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1/6/16' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.$anonfun$parse$1(TimestampFormatter.scala:78)
    ... 20 more
```

How to solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need (and in fact inappropriate) to set legacy time parser policy. You should use a single M/d if your day/month can have 1 or 2 digits. The number of M/d indicates the **minimum** number of digits for a day/month. This works on Spark 2 or 3.

```
df.show()
+---------+
|OrderDate|
+---------+
|   1/6/16|
| 11/12/16|
+---------+

df.withColumn('OrderDate', F.to_date('OrderDate', 'M/d/yy')).show()
+----------+
| OrderDate|
+----------+
|2016-01-06|
|2016-11-12|
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below config to fix the LEAGACY format issue.

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
```

Here is good read about it https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/whats-new-apache-spark-3-proleptic-calendar-date-time-management/read